# is there a hamiltonian circuit in the graph in the link below?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hamiltonian-cycle

Like the question says in the image in the link.

Is there a `hamilton circuit` in the graph above  ?

i found some `hamilton path` like :

```
c - b - a -j - i - h -  f - e - d - g
```

But no `hamilton circuit`

[image]

I cant add the picture in here since stackoverflow didnt allow me

Comment: Are you trying to write a program to find the circuits? If so, include what you've tried so far. If not, it's probably off-topic.

Comment: edit it XD thx for the notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot be a hamiltonian cycle.

Proof:

In a hamiltonian cycle, every vertex must be visited and no edge can be used twice. Thus, if a vertex has degree two, both its edges must be used in any such cycle.

`a`, `c`, and `g` are degree two, so it follows that if there is a hamiltonian cycle it must contain the path `j - a - b - c - d - g - h`. However, this path does not contain `e` but it contains two of `e`'s neighbors, `b` and `d`. `e` only has one remaining neighbor, `f`, so there is no way to extend the path to a hamiltonian cycle that contains `e`. Thus there can be no hamiltonian cycle in the graph.